# Use data between semicolons separated with space

Tags: sed

My output is as follows:

`scott name1;tiger name2;elephant name3;mouse name4;bla1 name5;bla2 name6`

I'd like to search for "scott" and ONLY get the string "name1" back.
How can I achieve this with sed?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "search" in this context: do you have multiple lines, one or more may begin with the string `scott`, or is there a single line in which `scott` may appear in an unspecified one of the semicolon-delimited fields?

Comment: You mention that the data that you show is the "output".  What outputs this data and could _that_ be changed to only output the stuff you're interested in? Also, can the fields contain embedded `;` characters or newlines? Apart from that, see also steeldriver's comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more verbose solution:

```bash
echo "scott name1;tiger name2;elephant name3;mouse name4;bla1 name5;bla2 name6" \
  | tr ';' '\n' | grep "scott" | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Comment: hope no need of for loop.... `echo "scott name1;tiger ..." | tr ';' '\n' | grep "scott" | cut -d ' ' -f 2`

Comment: This example is great. Will use this one!

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
echo "scott name1;tiger name2;elephant name3;mouse name4;bla1 name5;bla2 name6" \
  | awk -v RS=\; '$1=="scott"{print $2}'
```

The record separator `RS` is set to `;` to be able to capture the string `scott` as the first field `$1` of the record. When found, the second field `$2` is printed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can I pass a bash variable to awk so that I can use

myvar=scott

awk -v RS=\; '$1=="$myvar"{print $2}'

Thank you!

Comment: @JohannesP.W. `awk -v str="$name" ...` then use `str` in the `awk` code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```bash
echo "scott name1;tiger name2;elephant name3;mouse name4;bla1 name5;bla2 name6" \
  | sed -n -e 's/^scott \(\w\+\);.*/\1/p'
```

Just backreference the string between "scott " and ";".

Comment: Maybe match for `.*`instead of `^` and make the statement more generic: `findme='elephant' ; echo "scott name1;tiger name2;elephant name3;mouse name4;bla1 name5;bla2 name6"   | sed -n -e "s/.*$findme \(\w\+\);.*/\1/p"`

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "scott name1;tiger name2;elephant name3;mouse name4;bla1 name5;bla2 name6" \
  | sed -n 's/\(^\|.*;\)scott \([^;]*\).*/\2/p'
name1
```

or with "tiger":

```
$ echo "scott name1;tiger name2;elephant name3;mouse name4;bla1 name5;bla2 name6" \
  | sed -n 's/\(^\|.*;\)tiger \([^;]*\).*/\2/p'
name2
```

- `sed -n` disable automatic printing of pattern space
- `s/` substitute
- `\(^\|.*;\)` match the start of the line `^` or any characters followed by semicolon `.*;` as first capturing group with `\(...\`)
- `scott` match "scott" followed by a space character
- `\([^;]*\)` second capturing group, match any non-semicolon characters (the part we want)
- `.*` match any following characters
- `/\2/` replace with second capturing group
- `p` print match